# What's the proper way of catching an exception of method running in a different thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, exception, qthread

I am running a qml application with C++ plugin. Application is pretty simple:

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///ui/views/mainwindow.qml")));

return app.exec();
```

But qml plugin has a lot of code. To avoid freezes in qml I place object into a thread by `moveToThread()` and call methods by `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()` asynchronously by using `Qt::QueuedConnection` parameter. The problem is the methods I call by `invokeMethod` can throw an exception(s) and then the program will crash  because I can't catch them:

```
try {
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(&qlNetwork, "disconnect", Qt::QueuedConnection);
} catch (const std::runtime_error& e) {
    emit error(e.what());
}
```

Of course this code will not work because the call is non-blocking. The question is: how then can I catch exceptions from an object in different thread (QThread) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd create a wrapper slot that calls `disconnect` from another thread and handles the exception.

```
void ThisClass::wrapperMethod() {
    try {
        qlNetwork->disconnect();
    } catch (const std::runtime_error& e) {
        emit error(e.what());
    }
}
```

And then you invoke the wrapper method asynchronously:

```
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "wrapperMethod", Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

Make sure `wrapperMethod` is a `SLOT` or it is defined as `Q_INVOKABLE` and `ThisClass` instance is moved to a different thread.

---

**Possible solution using lambdas**

```
QTimer *t = new QTimer();
connect(t, &QTimer::timeout, this, [=]() {
    t->deleteLater();
    try {
        qlNetwork->disconnect();
    } catch (const std::runtime_error& e) {
        emit this->error(e.what());
    }
}, Qt::QueuedConnection);
/* don't forget to move the timer to the thread where
   you want the lambda to be executed*/
t->moveToThread(targetThread);
t->setSingleShot(true);
t->start(0);
```

---

**Solution using lambdas with QtConcurrent (Victor Polevoy)**

```
void ThisClass::performDisconnect() {
    QtConcurrent::run([this]() {
        try {
            this->qlNetwork.disconnect();
        } catch (const std::runtime_error& e) {
            emit error(e.what());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've thought about it but is not here any universal solution for such usual case?

Comment: What do you mean by universal solution? Exceptions have to handled synchronously in the same thread the method call is performed.

Comment: I mean a solution which can do that without any wrappers. For example, some internal `qt` wrapper of `QThread::run` which catches `(...)` and emits some signal or something like that.

Comment: Okay, can I do that at least with lambdas? My attempts are unsuccessfull.

Comment: I've added solution with `QtConcurrent` which is tested personally by me.

Comment: If you think your edit is the right answer then post it as an answer and accept it. You have the right of doing it.

Comment: I think it is good for others to know all possible ways. Why should we create another answer if it consists of yours by 2/3 ? What is the point? Why not to keep all the right solutions in one place? If you insist I can do that of course.

Comment: Cool. I'll add your solution to my answer too then. I'll just rename the method from `disconnect` to `doDisconnect` in order not to clash with `QObject`'s `disconnect` functions which are pretty important when working with Qt :)